# Unable to use Contacts API in Firefox OS app

Tags: javascript, firefox-os

I have gone through [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/B2G_OS/API/Contacts_API) and tried everything mentioned there, but I always getting error only.

I have tested in simulator "Firefox OS 2.2".

My manifest contains two permissions like:

```
"permissions": {
    "desktop-notification": {
      "description": "Needed for creating system notifications."
    },
    "contacts": {
      "description": "Needed for reading contacts"
    }
  },
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, just added access property to the manifest. Its working now.

```
"contacts": {
  "access": "readcreate"
}
```